# XSLT is to XML as what is to CSV?

Tags: java, scala, csv

I want to design a flexible way to add parsing logic for CSV files
without using Java or C#.

We know that XSLT can be used to manipulating XML files.

Is there a equivalent technology for CSV files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no XSLT of CSV, because CSV is fundamentally simpler than XML.

- XML represents general tree structures.
- CSV represents sets of tuples of fixed length.

Mapping between general tree structures is intrinsically more difficult than mapping between sets of fixed length tuples.  XSLT is a tool that helps meets the challenge for general tree structures.   Mapping between CSV is much easier and typically is done in an ad hoc manner directly in a general purpose programming language.

Comment: I agree with you at moment, however there are 2 thoughts 1) worth setting up a gihub CSLT project? 2) I am looking at a way to implementing my own scripting rules, which ultimately leads to the deliverable of point 1. or perhaps reusing some of the  jsr-223 script languages

Comment: Note that I was explaining why an XSLT of CSV hasn't come about -- not that it would have no value if it did.  Although the re-arrangement of CSV data will be easier, I could still see value in declarative ways to state (a) the re-arrangement and (b) the individual data conversion and cleansing functions that together specify how each output CSV column derives from the input CSV column(s).   Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to transform the CSV into XML and then use XSLT to transform that.

[Here](http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html) is an XSLT transform that seems to try to do that.

Comment: it would have worked, but it's against my goal, which is trying to simplify things..

Answer (score 0):

I've been using scala-csv for a project I've been working on and I haven't had much trouble with it yet. It saved me the trouble of writing a bunch of regular expressions, and if that's what you're looking for, it should help you out.

https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv

Comment: sorry thats's just another way of using general programming language to do things